# touch Move of text Over Image

Tags: android

I want to move the text over an image to fix the text on the desired place over the image.
I run this code successfully But its not optimum as its not user friendly.
Text Movement doesn't match to finger's pick and drop even sometimes.
If anybody have better code Please share with me or let me know if i am missing something.

```
//Listeners for the Canvas that is being awarded
                 popImgae.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener(){

                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                            someGlobalXvariable = e.getX();
                            someGlobalYvariable = e.getY();
                            setTextPosition();

                            //saveImage(imgRecord.get(1),leftPos,topPos,popText.getTextSize(),popText.getText().toString());
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                                     public void setTextPosition(){
                                         try {
                                        redrawImage(imgRecord.get(1),Integer.parseInt(imgRecord.get(8)),imgRecord.get(6),Integer.parseInt(imgRecord.get(9)));
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO: handle exception
                                            System.out.println("##########Error in setTextPositio========="+e.getMessage());
                                        }

                                     }

                                    ///Redrawing the image & touchin Move of the Canvas with text
                                    public void redrawImage(String path,float sizeValue,String textValue,int colorValue) {

                                        //Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fashion_pic);
                                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                        try {
                                             options.inMutable = true;
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO: handle exception
                                            System.out.println("#############Error is======"+e.getMessage());
                                        }

                                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);
                                        //bm = imageManipulation.convertToMutable(bm);

                                        proxy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                                        Canvas c = new Canvas(proxy);

                                        //Here, we draw the background image.
                                        c.drawBitmap(bm, new Matrix(), null);

                                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                                        paint.setColor(colorValue); // Text Color
                                        paint.setStrokeWidth(30); // Text Size
                                        paint.setTextSize(sizeValue);

                                        System.out.println("Values passing=========="+someGlobalXvariable+",   "+someGlobalYvariable+",   "
                                              +sizeValue+",   "+textValue);

                                        //Here, we draw the text where the user last touched.
                                        c.drawText(textValue, someGlobalXvariable, someGlobalYvariable, paint);

                                        popImgae.setImageBitmap(proxy);
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyView  extends View{

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            //get your drawable image 
            setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawText("text", x, y, new Paint());
        }

        float x,y;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            x= event.getX();
            y= event.getX();
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: in your activity class.. setContentView(new MYView(this));